# Error MySQL: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket (Ubuntu 14.04.5)

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql

```
mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

service mysql status
mysql stop/waiting

service mysql restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start

find / -name mysql.sock
/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

However, **I cannot find the file mysql.sock in my server.** I don't know how to deal with this problem. Is there any information else I can provide to help me get assistance?
I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you've installed `mysql-client` and not `mysql-server`. Or may the MySQL server service has not been started.

**To install MySQL server, follow these steps (Or just to start mysql service, jump directly to step 3):**

1. Install the MySQL server by using the Ubuntu package manager: `sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. The installer installs MySQL and all dependencies.
2. After the installation process is complete, run the following command to set up MySQL: `/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`. The secure installer goes through the process of setting up MySQL including creating a root user password. It will prompt you for some security options, including removing remote access to the root user and setting the root password.
3. After the installation is complete, you can start the database service by running the following command. If the service is already started, a message informs you that the service is already running: `sudo service mysql start`.
4. After the installation is complete, you can start the database service by running the following command. If the service is already started, a message informs you that the service is already running: `sudo service mysql start`.
5. To ensure that the database server launches after a reboot, run the following command: `sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d mysql defaults`.

**Start the MySQL Shell:**

1. At the command prompt, run the following command to launch the the mysql shell and enter it as the root user: `/usr/bin/mysql -u root -p`.
2. When you’re prompted for a password, enter the one you set at install time or, if you haven’t set one, press Enter to submit no password.

Hope this helps you. If not, visit https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu/ or comment below. Thanks!

Comment: @fordyy You can accept my answer if this helped you!

Comment: run<code>    /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation<code> , the output<code>    ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)<code>;run<code>      sudo service mysql start<code>, the output<code>    start: Job failed to start<code>

Comment: @fordyy Have you tried to install `mysql-server`?

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

Comment: @fordyy Try uninstalling and installing mysql-server again.

Comment: @fordyy Or reset mysql to defaults using this command: `sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d mysql defaults` then reboot and try to configure mysql again.

Comment: when I run the code'    /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation', it requires me to enter current password for root and I reallly do this. However, it returns that '    ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'. I also run the code '    sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d mysql defaults' and reboot my linode, but it seems nothing changes. Is there anything else I can do to start mysql?

Comment: @fordyy Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling MySQL? I think some files have might got corrupted. Reinstalling MySQL will replace the corrupted files with good ones and your database system will start running without error.

Comment: Will this damage my data in my website? I'm worried about this. Besides,I'm not very clear about how to uninstall and reinstall MySQL.

Comment: @fordyy Did your problem solved? 'Coz I'm now getting the same issue too...

Comment: I try uninstalling and installing mysql and now it can work normally. However, the data in my website was damaged. I redo the website completely. I found that the data had been damaged in /usr/local/mysql/var before my website went wrong. I don't know the reason for this problem. The VPS provider that I used is linode. I used the backup to restore to the day when the website worked well. But it doesn't work. This is all I know.